# Reserve/Assign a new row in another table with each row added in one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'll like to find out if it's possible to do the following:

- after insertion of data into table a, a row will be created automatically in table b and the Note_Id (its primary key) will be stored in one of the attributes (which is a foreign key that references to the primary key in table b) in table a.

---

```
 CREATE TABLE table_a ( D_Id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 User_Id int(8) not null,
 Note_Id int(5) not null, -- this is the foreign key that points to table b 
 PRIMARY KEY (D_Id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

 CREATE TABLE table_b ( Note_Id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 Note_Description varchar(50) null, 
 PRIMARY KEY (Note_Id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks!

```
 delimiter $$
 CREATE TRIGGER ins_Document
 AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_A FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   set @notenum=(Select max(Note_Id) from TABLE_B);
   if(@notenum=0) then begin new.Note_Id=1;
   end;
   else
     new.Note_Id=@notenum+1;
   end if;
 INSERT INTO TABLE_B (Note_Id) VALUES (NEW.Note_Id); 
 END$$
 delimiter ;
```

Comment: Why? This sounds like a bit of backwards design.

Comment: @gvee Sorry I'm new to this hence I thought the easiest way is so. I'm trying to "reserve a slot" for any notes (if it is going to be uploaded) and link it up with the corresponding Document. Is there a better way to do this? Pls do share. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to reserve a slot. Just create one when needed!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into triggers: [Create Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html)
Here you can react on events like inserts into a table and define respective actions for that.

Comment: Hi. I have the following code but it is not working.

delimiter $$ CREATE TRIGGER ins_Document AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_A FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
set @notenum=(Select max(Note_Id) from TABLE_B);  

if(@notenum=0) then 
begin
new.Note_Id=1;
end;
else
new.Note_Id=@notenum+1;
end if; 
    INSERT INTO TABLE_B (Note_Id) VALUES (NEW.Note_Id);
     END$$ delimiter ;

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Does it create errors? And please format your code...

Comment: Oops. Sorry. After the insertion into Table_A, there is nothing inserted into Table_B.

Comment: Will `select max(Note_Id) from table_b` not result in NULL on an empty table_b instead of 0? And I think it should be `set new.Note_Id=@notenum+1;` in the else block. Otherwise it would just be a comparison, not an assignment.